# Issues with installing Apache Superset on Kubernetes with Rancher

Tags: apache-superset

I tried installing Superset by following the steps provided in https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/superset/superset.

Postgresql and redis managed to install correctly.

When i am running `helm install my-superset superset/superset --version 0.12.6` it takes a lot of time and returns

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: 1 error occurred:
        * timed out waiting for the condition
```

and some pods are in error status

```
C:\Users\Comarch>kubectl get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
my-redis-master-0                     1/1     Running            0             11m
my-redis-replicas-0                   1/1     Running            0             11m
my-postgresql-0                       1/1     Running            0             11m
my-redis-replicas-1                   1/1     Running            0             11m
my-redis-replicas-2                   1/1     Running            0             10m
my-superset-postgresql-0              1/1     Running            0             7m4s
my-superset-init-db-mhqpn             0/1     Error              0             7m4s
my-superset-redis-master-0            1/1     Running            0             7m4s
my-superset-init-db-s8g6z             0/1     Error              0             6m34s
my-superset-init-db-6kngd             0/1     Error              0             6m8s
my-superset-init-db-tjvtf             0/1     Error              0             5m23s
my-superset-init-db-27x6z             0/1     Error              0             3m57s
my-superset-init-db-tndb6             0/1     Error              0             72s
my-superset-7449574d54-fvlgf          0/1     Running            1 (63s ago)   7m4s
my-superset-worker-85b4c79494-fqg8c   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (14s ago)   7m4s
```

Logs from k3s

```
I0226 14:08:35.678505    1224 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="e364b25e0b28f773a7bcd14d8f3092ddb9663b9a80e37f82b1a52551e74feba4"
E0226 14:08:35.680011    1224 pod_workers.go:1298] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"superset\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=superset pod=my-superset-worker-85b4c79494-fqg8c_default(102794ea-195f-414a-a218-ec474173736c)\"" pod="default/my-superset-worker-85b4c79494-fqg8c" podUID="102794ea-195f-414a-a218-ec474173736c"
```

Logs from docker

```
time="2024-02-26T14:09:32.963550813Z" level=error msg="collecting stats for 41bce38aca76aea4d7f668ca38619991711f7210030e187799f424a5ed46d697: no metrics received"
time="2024-02-26T14:09:33.218075523Z" level=error msg="loading cgroup for 106958" error="cgroups: cannot find cgroup mount destination"
```

There are no errors in the logs of individual pods. There is only a warning about SECRET_KEY

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    WARNING
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A Default SECRET_KEY was detected, please use superset_config.py to override it.
Use a strong complex alphanumeric string and use a tool to help you generate
a sufficiently random sequence, ex: openssl rand -base64 42
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Refusing to start due to insecure SECRET_KEY
[2024-02-26 14:16:31 +0000] [634] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 634)
Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/app/pythonpath/superset_config.py]
[2024-02-26 14:16:32 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Worker (pid:634) exited with code 1
[2024-02-26 14:16:32 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Worker (pid:634) exited with code 1.
[2024-02-26 14:16:32 +0000] [659] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 659
```

```
Redis version: 18.16.1
PostgreSQL version: 14.2.3
Helm version: 3.14.1
```

I tried installing on different versions of redis and postgresql and with my_values.yaml. The result is always the same. I will add that I am not familiar with Kubernetes.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `init` pod couldn't run successfully because you didn't provide a necessary `SECRET_KEY`.

> A Default `SECRET_KEY` was detected, please use superset_config.py to
> override it. Use a strong complex alphanumeric string and use a tool
> to help you generate a sufficiently random sequence, ex: `openssl rand -base64 42`
>
> Refusing to start due to insecure SECRET_KEY
>
> [2024-02-26 14:16:31+0000] [634] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 634)

The [README on artifacthub](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/superset/superset#tl-dr) provides the solution:

> Make sure you set your own `SECRET_KEY` to something unique and secret.
> This secret key is used by Flask for securely signing the session
> cookie and will be used to encrypt sensitive data on Superset's
> metadata database. It should be a long random bytes or str.
>
> On helm this can be set on `extraSecretEnv.SUPERSET_SECRET_KEY` or
> `configOverrides.secrets`

The [official Apache Superset documentation states](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes#important-settings):

> Make sure, you set a unique strong complex alphanumeric string for
> your SECRET_KEY and use a tool to help you generate a sufficiently
> random sequence.
>
> To generate a good key you can run, `openssl rand -base64 42`
>
> ```
> `configOverrides:`
>   `secret: |`
>     `SECRET_KEY = 'YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_GENERATED_SECRET_KEY'`
> ```

Comment: At work they confused me a bit, saying that this warning always appears. Now it works properly. Thank you very much for your help.